# Update form from another scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to update a record from the view of another scaffold, the problem is that it sends me the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"pedidosliberados"}
```

I'm showing one form per record
this is my form:

```
<% @pedidosliberados.each do |pedidoliberado| %>
                <tr id="pedido_liberado_<%= pedidoliberado.id %>">
                  <td class="component_name_body_col"><%=pedidoliberado.try(:Client)%></td>

                  <td class="component_name_body_col">
                    <%= form_for(pedidoliberado, :method => :put, remote: true, :url => {:controller =>'pedidosliberados', :action => 'update'}, html: {class: "form-horizontal "}) do |f| %><!--ajax-->
                      <%= f.text_field :Status, value: "1" %>
                      <%= submit_tag "Actualizar", class: "btn btn-primary"%>

                    <% end %>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
```

my route:

```
  resources :pedidosliberados
```

my action update from controller pedidosliberados:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @pedidoliberado.update(pedidoliberado_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @pedidoliberado, notice: 'Pedidoliberado was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @pedidoliberado 
        format.js {} 


      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @pedidoliberado.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         format.js {} 
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why are you using `remote: true` in your forms? Are you updating using `ajax`?

Comment: Can you show your `update` action from your `pedidosliberados` controller?

Comment: @Gerry The update action is from "pedidosliberados". Sorry I already update my post

Comment: Ohh, my bad, my answer got nothing to do with it, i'll update it. Try removing `:url => {:controller =>'pedidosliberados', :action => 'update'}` from your `form`.

Comment: @Gerry If I remove it it shows me the following error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pedidosliberados", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Ok, try putting it back but add `:id` along with `:contoller` and `:action`.

Comment: But maybe `pedidoliberado` is empty or doesn't contain any `id`.

Comment: @Gerry Many thanks you are right, should have passed the id, I did not imagine it because of the fact that in the editing forms do not place it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using an incomplete route, that is `/update`; you need to add the `id` of the object to be updated, something like `/update/12` where `12` is the id of the object. So in your code you could remove the `:url` attribute and you will be fine.

So your view, now should look like this:

```
<% @pedidosliberados.each do |pedidoliberado| %>
  <tr id="pedido_liberado_<%= pedidoliberado.id %>">
    <td class="component_name_body_col"><%=pedidoliberado.try(:Client)%></td>

    <td class="component_name_body_col">
      <%= form_for(pedidoliberado, :method => :put, remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal "}) do |f| %><!--ajax-->
        <%= f.text_field :Status, value: "1" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Actualizar", class: "btn btn-primary"%>

      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This works because rails automatically assigns the correct controller and action for your object (when using REST routes).

**UPDATE**

If you want to explicity assign the url, then use `:url` like you are doing, but adding `:id` (remember, you need to specify the `id` of the object to be updated). So, your `form` should look something like this:

```
<%= form_for(pedidoliberado, method: :put, remote: true, url: { controller: 'pedidosliberados', action: 'update', id: pedidoliberado.id }, html: { class: "form-horizontal " }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I already add the "format.js { }" but it still shows me the same error: No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"pedidosliberados"}